# Storing application on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Welcome, I have just started learning Amazon cloud services. For test issues I userd Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my app written on Java. For the first time I used free/trial version for 750 hourse standalone app, and I was quite surprised that Elastic Beanstalk is using S3 (Storage) and it gives only 1k for POST and 2k for GET queries, limit is very low. So my question is, is it possible for Elastic Beanstalk not use S3 container? As shown in description to my web-app , Elastic Beanstalk is using preconfigured web-server running on Unix systems. Why it does not use it's own storage (30GB trial).

Comment: S3 is just used for storing some files like deployment files and log archives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you have with your account. However if you go to this Aws pricing page http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html you see when you add an Ec2 node you can choose one with internal storage with and ssd or hdd.

With the free trial you are probably using Amazon's preconfigured set up and it probably is designed using it's web architecture it outlines, which is Ec2's run the web app and an S3 node is used for storage. You should consider using the data base to store program and application files or use a general Ec2 and just run nginx or apache or what ever software you want. This will have more of a feeling like running your own server at home except you ssh into an AWS server instead. It may be simpler too.

Amazon's preconfigured Ec2's are probably designed to support large web applications in which case utilizing a data base for web application files makes sense.